# How to execute .exe file through Network

Tags: windows, networking

I wonder how I can run "execute" a .exe file through all devices which are connected to the same network so let's setup the scenario:

1- Our network name is "Geeks" 
2- There are 10 devices connected to "Geeks"
3- I have "program.exe"
4- I want to run it on the 10 Devices whom are connected to "Geeks"

---

Regards,
AlaaEddin

Comment: It may be not possible. The connection network is a protocol at the network layer, and the running program is an application layer protocol.

Comment: Depends what you can leverage: I assume it's not an Active Directory domain, which would give you startup/login scripts?  I assume all the computers aren't running some management agent that could be used to deploy the program?  Microsoft tool PsExec might be a good option without the above but of course you would then ideally need a common admin account. Some thought might need to be given to firewalls.